# Format inbook reference in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have very strict requirements on how my reference list must look like. The standard biblatex styles are close but need some fine tuning. I was able to change a few things for electronic and book references. But I have spent quite some time now to format the `inbook` reference type and so far there is no luck. Here is a picture of what it needs to look like:

[image]

I use JabRef and get this record:

```
@INBOOK{donmeyer2008,
  chapter = {Quantitative Research},
  pages = {714-9},
  title = {The SAGE encyclopedia of qualitative research methods},
  publisher = {Thousand Oaks: SAGE Publications, Inc},
  year = {2008},
  editor = {L.M. Given},
  author = {Donmeyer, R.},
  owner = {sylvia.richter},
  timestamp = {2013.04.21}
}
```

I changed the order of fields in the `standard.bx` file (that works) and added format info to `biblatex.cfg`, but that does not work. Whatever I enter there is disregarded. This line for example does nothing:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{byeditor+others}{in #1 (ed.)}
```

I chose `byeditor+others` because this is how the `standard.bbx` prints the editor: `\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}`. I have also tried just `byeditor` or `editor` but apparently this line is never called. 
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the editor cannot be displayed with

```
\printfield{editor}
```

Instead

```
\printnames[byeditor]{editor}
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably that you never call `\printfield` with the "byeditor+others" format, i.e.:

```
\printfield[byeditor+others]{somefield}
```

Formats are either called explicitly by name as above or default to the field name:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{somecode}
\printfield{note}
```

`\usebibmacro` doesn't use the formats, it's just a way to group/call multiple macros. Don't forget that you have to declare/use the first data typed format:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat + \printfield
\DeclareListFormat + \printlist
\DeclareNameFormat + \printname
```

If you look up these macros in the biblatex manual, it's all explained.

Comment: Sry for the late reply. I have now added `\printfield{editor}` to the `standard.bbx` but that doesn't even produce any output

Comment: We'll need a MWE at this point to see what you're doing.